# Aggregate by using createdAt with Parse server does not work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform, aggregate

I am trying to make aggregation with a Parse server (back4app, Parse server v2.7.1) but while I am able to aggregate by using the fields I explicitly created in the mongoDb, I am unable to aggregate by using the fields 'createdAt' or 'updatedAt'.

As an example, if I invoke:

```
query.aggregate(pipeline)
```

With:

```
{ 
  project: {
   objectId: "$objectId",
   instr: "$instructions" 
  } 
};
```

I have an array of records like:

```
{instr: "1", objectId: "CNHAdpMD0U"}
```

If on the other side I use:

```
{ 
  project: {
    objectId: "$objectId",
    date: "$createdAt" 
  } 
};
```

I have just:

```
{objectId: "CNHAdpMD0U"}
```

Finally, the pipeline:

```
{ 
  project: {
    objectId: "$objectId",
    dayOfYear: { $dayOfYear: "$createdAt" }
  } 
};
```

Gives "500 - internal server error", but I guess is due to the missing retrieval of "$createdAt".

Comment: eg. by a collection with columns "instructions: string, createdAt: date, updatedAt: date, objectId" I expected with the second pipeline { objectId: "CNHAdpMD0U", date: "2018-01-01T08:15:39.736Z" }

Comment: I don't know how to check mongoDb version, as it is hidden by Parse server. There is no exception (no catch hence), all request are successful at javascript level, including the last that returns "500" as http response

Comment: Did you followed the guide? http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/

Comment: Yes, and in the "aggregate" part there is no specific note on createdAt. Just "Most operations in Mongo Aggregate Documentation will work with Parse Server", so I assumed aggregation by createdAt and dayOfYear (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/) would work

Answer (score 2):

it seems there is a fix on Parse Server about this. At the moment, you can use like example the cloud function below:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('yourFunctionName', (req, res) => {
    var pipeline = [{
        group: { 
            objectId: { day: { $dayOfMonth: "$_created_at" }, month: { $month: "$_created_at" }, year: { $year: "$_created_at" } }, 
            count: { $sum: 1 } }
        }
    ];
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.aggregate(pipeline, { useMasterKey: true })
        .then(function(results) {
            res.success(results);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            res.error(error)
        });
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Usage of "_created_at" instead of "createdAt" is the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks also for the suggestion of the bug - found: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/4678

Comment: Hi Amedeo, good to know that it worked! I'm happy about it :)

Comment: @nataliec how we can add group by another filed like "gender" at same time?

Comment: Hi @Osiris, can you please paste here how you are trying to do that?